# Powershell Sql Query is bombing at the the sql Data Adapter fill line

Tags: sql, powershell

The error is this:

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "The SelectCommand
> property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'."

Here is my code:

```
function ConnectSQL () {
    $dataSource             = "D-DBA"
    $initialCatalog         = "DatabaseName"
    $applicationName        = "Whatever"
    $connectionString       = "Data Source=$dataSource;Initial Catalog=$initialCatalog; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=30; Application Name=$applicationName"
    $conn                   = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString  = $connectionString
    $conn.Open()
    Return $conn
}

function RetrieveSqlData ($dataName, $conn) {
    $query  = "SELECT Data FROM TableName WHERE Name = '$dataName'"
    $cmd    = new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query,$conn)
    $ds     = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    $da     = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
    [void]$da.fill($ds)
    Return $ds.Tables[0]
}

$conn = ConnectSQL
$data = RetrieveSqlData -dataName "RecordName" -conn $conn
```

It's failing at this line:

```
[void]$da.fill($ds)
```

When I run this from my PowerShell console, it works perfect.  But when I execute it from a script, it fails with the above error.  I have no idea what could be going wrong here.  I've made slight modifications to the code to keep stuff private, but the logic is all the exact same.

I have tried checking that it's running as the same user manually and with the script, that they are both running as administrator, and that the PowerShell version is the same in both cases.  I have even checked to make sure that the $conn.State is "Open" when it runs from the script.  All of that checks out.

Comment: ```system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)``` *should* set ```$cmd``` as the ```SelectCommand``` according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-data-sqlclient-sqldataadapter-ctor(system-data-sqlclient-sqlcommand). You could check if that property is actually set in the console *and* the script - the failing line may be a symptom of a problem earlier in the code. Also, have you tried restarting your console session to make sure you've not got unexpected variables / state hanging around that let it work?

Comment: You were right.  It was a problem elsewhere in the code.  It was with one of my wrapper functions that called RetrieveSqlData not passing it the $conn variable.  Thanks for your help!